# Finding the shortest distance between two line segments(defined with start and end points).

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two line segments in 2D plane like:

$$L_1 \to x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2 = [352, 219, 843, 967]$$

$$L_2 \to x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2 = [481, 355, 717, 882]$$

Is there any way to find shortest distance between two line segments?

Comment: I chaged lines to line segments. Actually my purpose is merge two line segments if their distance and slope is close to each other.

Comment: I have an idea, which I would like to share, which **may not work**, but I need you to show work first.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does your background include knowledge of 2-variable Calculus, and (for example) minimizing $f(x,y)$ where $a\leq x\leq b$, and $c \leq y\leq d$?

Comment: @user2661923 I am not good with Calculus but I can search the net to understand the terms and concepts you use.

Comment: @math-lover Check distances from both ends is not work sometimes. For example one line segment is too long and other is too short. Even short segment has same slope and close enough to long segment, the distances between both ends can be too big. Like this https://i.imgur.com/7bhjQ7P.png

Comment: "Actually my purpose is merge two line segments...".  I am guessing that this problem was not given to you as a classroom or book assignment.  Assuming so, I see this as problematic, because my *instinct* (which may be wrong) is that the general solution **will** involve 2 variable Calculus.  What is your math background, how did you happen to be confronted with this problem, and is there an *underlying goal* (rather than explicitly minimizing the distance between two line segments)?  I advise **against** trying to study 2-variable Calculus *on-the-fly*.

Comment: Thank you I understand. @user2661923 I will study 2-variable Calculus thank you.

Comment: If you still can't solve the problem, then I recommend deleting this entire query, and re-posting the query.  In the new posting, indicate your math background and where this problem came from.  Further indicate any *on-the-fly* single variable or 2-variable Calculus that you've examined.  Further, **show any work that you've tried** as part of the query.  This will give mathSE reviewers all the excuse they need to hand you an answer.  Personally, I never studied 2-variable Calculus, therefore I *merely* **strongly suspect** that that is where the general solution lies.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your advice. If I can't solve the problem, I will do as you said.

Comment: See this link it it helps - it applies the same set of things I was mentioning earlier. Intersecting, overlapping, shortest distance etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541150/connect-two-line-segments/11427699#11427699

Comment: @math-lover thank you I will check.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, the minimum distance is zero since the lines
$$L_1 \qquad \qquad y=\frac{748 }{491}x-\frac{155767}{491}$$
$$L_2 \qquad \qquad y=\frac{527 }{236}x-\frac{169707}{236}$$

intersect at $$x=\frac{2739125}{4837}\sim 566.286\qquad \qquad y=\frac{2638331}{4837}\sim545.448$$ which are inside the bounds of both segments.